# Duplicate foreign keys and columns being created for an id EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-3.1

Got a issue with ef core 3.1 creating duplicate columns for a id field from another table. i currently have a ApplicationUser entity that inherits from IdentityUser, and a property entity that stores an ApplicationUser id as UserId.

```
 public class Property
    {
        public Guid PropertyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address PropertyAddress { get; set; }
        public bool IsHome { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public IEnumerable<Property> properties { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class PropertyConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Property>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Property> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(p => p.PropertyId);
            builder.HasOne(p => p.PropertyAddress).WithOne();
            builder.HasOne(p => p.User).WithMany(p => p.properties).HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        }
    }
```

```
 public class ApplicationUserConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("User");
            builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.HasMany<Property>().WithOne(p => p.User).HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);
        }
    }
```

Above are my classes and i have run the migration which produces this table for property.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Property",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    PropertyId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    AddressId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    IsHome = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ApplicationUserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Property", x => x.PropertyId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Property_Address_AddressId",
                        column: x => x.AddressId,
                        principalTable: "Address",
                        principalColumn: "AddressId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Property_User_ApplicationUserId",
                        column: x => x.ApplicationUserId,
                        principalTable: "User",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Property_User_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "User",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });
```

As you can see it is creating a UserId column and foreign key which is correct. but its also producing a ApplicationUserId and i cannot figure out what is causing it.

Any Idea?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `HasMany(u => u.properties)`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks that has sorted the issue such a small error for 2 hours of headaches. if you create an answer i will mark it as may be useful for someone else caught out by this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your fluent API configuration

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder) {
    builder.HasMany<Property>()
        .WithOne(p => p.User)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);
}
```

You are simply saying that there is a one-to-many relationship between the `ApplicationUser` and `Property` entities, but not which members are involved from the *many* side. Indeed there may be multiple associations between `Property` and `ApplicationUser`.

To get it working, specify the members involved on both ends by adjusting your configuration like so

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder) {
    builder.HasMany(u => u.properties)
        .WithOne(p => p.User)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have both:

```
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

If you don't wan't `User` to reference the `User` table you'll have to ignore it. Something like this (I can't remember if it's the exact syntax)

```
   builder.Property(p => p.User).Ignore();
```

But that means that when you fetch `Property` from the context `User` will be null. Also if you attach an `ApplicationUser` to `Property` and then save the property - neither the `User` nor the relantioship will be written to the database, and you'll need to set `UserId` manually.

Comment: but from my understanding this should be allowed as show here : https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship#fully-defined-relationship